# objective-c, PDF, How to solve "failed to parse embedded CMap." issue in PDF Seaching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, pdf

I am trying perform searching text in PDF, My project works fine on mostly PDF, but it fails to search text on some PDF, and xcode shows this message on console :
**"failed to parse embedded CMap."** How to solve this issue, So that I can search text on all PDF. Any suggestion will be great. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is impossible to search for text in all PDFs. This is for two main reasons:

1. PDFs use character codes that do not correspond to Unicode. A Cmap is used in this case to associate PDF character codes with a Unicode, but is not required to be present in the PDF document.
2. Even if a Cmap is included, the characters of text are not guaranteed to appear in order in the PDF document. PDF displays the glyphs corresponding to a character code based on geometry not on text.